# Answer notification in tab title

Tags: feature-request, notifications

In my opinion it's nice to have such option - when in your browser opened a lot of tabs but you're waiting for the answer on important question you may take short look at SO tab and see that you have an answer or a comment.

Comment: I believe the app will give you a notification if one of your questions is answered. Not quite the same, but maybe it could help.

Comment: There’s [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox](http://stackapps.com/q/3780). Also, cross-site dupe: [Does Stack Overflow have desktop Notifications for Chrome or Firefox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156050/289905).

Comment: @S.L.Barth i can confirm the app does give you notifications

Answer (score 43):

**[I fully agree!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246404/178816)**

Activity on posts could show as counters in the title of tabs. For example, like this:

[image]

Since all content that comes in is loaded via ajax, any time the trigger to load (1 new answer, 1 more comment, etc.) that content is called, it could simply increase the tab counter.

Comment: also something like [this library](https://github.com/tommoor/tinycon) could be useful to save title space in browsers that support it

Comment: @The_Lone_Devil that may be a better option as titles can't be seen when tabs are pinned yet favicon are still shown.

Comment: @The_Lone_Devil My browser does that automatically for any tab whose title begins with a number in parens